# Remove libvirt's dhcp lease entry using virsh

Tags: libvirt, dnsmasq

Using:

```
$ virsh version
 Compiled against library: libvirt 1.3.1
 Using library: libvirt 1.3.1
 Using API: QEMU 1.3.1
 Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.5.0
$
$
$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
 Release:   16.04
 Codename:  xenial
```

I'd like to remove a libvirt's dhcp lease entry using virsh.

```
$ virsh net-list
Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
default              active     yes           yes
docker-machines      active     yes           yes

$ virsh net-dhcp-leases docker-machines
Expiry Time          MAC address        Protocol  IP address               Hostname        Client ID or DUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-10 16:15:38  52:54:00:8e:15:f5  ipv4      192.168.42.22/24         minikubecluster ff:c2:72:f6:09:00:02:00:00:ab:11:af:a8:d1:af:21:23:5c:49
2017-05-10 16:09:57  52:54:00:c6:51:45  ipv4      192.168.42.23/24         registry        01:52:54:00:c6:51:45
```

I've tried different option using `virsh net-update delete`, but I keep getting this errors:

```
couldn't locate a matching dhcp host entry in network 'docker-machines'
```

Is this because libvirt's lease files are changed (they are named after the network interface and the format is JSON)? If so, how can I then do this then?

Comment: In case anyone is looking at this question and does not have a strict requirement of using `virsh` cli - there is `dhcp_release` program (on Debian provided by `dnsmasq-utils` package) which can be used exactly for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic leases are difficult to remove using virsh.

Deleting the var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virbr0.* files will work for the default network.
Assuming everything is off i.e. all your VMs are down

```
sudo rm var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virbr0.*
```